# Manipulate the url using routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

In my website I have the following route defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Specific Product",
   url: "product/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In that way I want customers to be able to add the ID of the product and go to the product page.

SEO advisors have said that it would be better if we could add a description of the product on the URL, like product-name or something. So the URL should look something like:

> /product/my-cool-product-name/123

or

> /product/my-cool-product-name-123

Of course the description is stored in the db and I cannot do that with a url rewrite (or can I?)

Should I add a redirection on my controller (this would seem to do the job, but it just doesn't feel right)

On a few sites I checked they do respond with a `301 Moved Permanently`. Is that really the best approach?

**UPDATE**

As per  `Stephen Muecke`'s comment I checked on what is happening on SO.

The suggested url was my own [Manipulate the url using routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071228) and i opened the console to see any redirections. Here is a screenshot:

[image: SO-301-response]

Comment: Its called a slug, and you can use a custom action filter to look up the database value based on the ID and append it to the route. [This article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/21/manipulating-action-method-parameters.aspx/) gives an explanation of what you can do

Comment: @StephenMuecke Interesting article. But it seems that this would accept the human readable url to figure out the id. I want to put the id in the address bar and then change it to the human readable one. As i see it, the best solution would be a mix of your proposal (slug) and a 301 response.

Comment: You just need to do the reverse. Base on the `id` route vale, look up the database to get the slug and modify the route values (just how SO works - e.g. type the following in the address bar `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071228` to see it works)

Comment: @StephenMuecke As suspected, even SO responds with a `301 Moved Permanently` I will update the question to show you the console.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - if you entered the above url in the address bar it will display this question with the revised address being `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071228/manipulate-the-url-using-routing`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Check my screenshot. I enter the url and i get a response 301 (see the status next to the link in the screenshot). So what happens is the browser asks the server for the url i entered, the server responds that this has been permanently moved to another location and also provides the new location. So the browser now will request anew the second url. In these cases if i am correct the browser is clever enough to cache the new url, so it doesn't do the extra trip the next time. Your comment about slug (which i did not know) was really very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all very special thanks to **@StephenMuecke** for giving the hint for slugs and also the url he suggested.

I would like to post my approach which is a mix of that url and several other articles.

My goal was to be able to have the user enter a url like:

> /product/123

and when the page loads to show in the address bar something like:

> /product/my-awsome-product-name-123

I checked several web sites that have this behaviour and it seems that a `301 Moved Permanently` response is used in all i checked. Even SO as shown in my question uses `301` to add the title of the question. I thought that there would be a different approach that would not need the second round trip....

So the total solution i used in this case was:

1. I created a `SlugRouteHandler` class which looks like:

   ```
   public class SlugRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
   {
       protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
       {
           var url = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.TrimStart('/');

           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
           {
               var slug = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["slug"];
               int id;

               //i care to transform only the urls that have a plain product id. If anything else is in the url i do not mind, it looks ok....
               if (Int32.TryParse(slug, out id))
               {
                   //get the product from the db to get the description
                   var product = dc.Products.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
                   //if the product exists then proceed with the transformation. 
                   //if it does not exist then we could addd proper handling for 404 response here.
                   if (product != null)
                   {
                       //get the description of the product
                       //SEOFriendly is an extension i have to remove special characters, replace spaces with dashes, turn capital case to lower and a whole bunch of transformations the SEO audit has requested
                       var description = String.Concat(product.name, "-", id).SEOFriendly(); 
                       //transform the url
                       var newUrl = String.Concat("/product/",description);
                       return new RedirectHandler(newUrl);
                   }
               }

           }

           return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
       }

   }
   ```
2. From the above i need to also create a `RedirectHandler` class to handle the redirections. This is actually a direct copy from [here](http://blog.abodit.com/2010/04/a-simple-redirect-route-handler-for-asp-net-3-5-routing/)

   ```
   public class RedirectHandler : IHttpHandler
   {
       private string newUrl;

       public RedirectHandler(string newUrl)
       {
           this.newUrl = newUrl;
       }

       public bool IsReusable
       {
           get { return true; }
       }

       public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
       {
           httpContext.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
           httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 301;
           httpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Location", newUrl);
           return;
       }
   }
   ```

With this 2 classes i can transform product ids to SEO friendly urls.

In order to use these i need to modify my route to use the `SlugRouteHandler` class, which leads to :

3. Call `SlugRouteHandler` class from the route

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Specific Product",
      url: "product/{slug}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index" }
   ).RouteHandler = new SlugRouteHandler();
   ```

Here comes the use of the [link](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/21/manipulating-action-method-parameters.aspx/) **@StephenMuecke** mentioned in his comment.

We need to find a way to map the new SEO friendly url to our actual controller. My controller accepts an integer id but the url will provide a string.

4. We need to create an Action filter to handle the new param passed before calling the controller

   ```
   public class SlugToIdAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
   {

       public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {
           var slug = filterContext.RouteData.Values["slug"] as string;
           if (slug != null)
           {
               //my transformed url will always end in '-1234' so i split the param on '-' and get the last portion of it. That is my id. 
               //if an id is not supplied, meaning the param is not ending in a number i will just continue and let something else handle the error
               int id;
               Int32.TryParse(slug.Split('-').Last(), out id);
               if (id != 0)
               {
                   //the controller expects an id and here we will provide it
                   filterContext.ActionParameters["id"] = id;
               }
           }
           base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
       }
   }
   ```

Now what happens is that the controller will be able to accept a non numeric id which ends in a number and provide its view without modifying the content of the controller. We will only need to add the filter attribute on the controller as shown in the next step.

I really do not care if the product name is actually the product name. You could try fetching the following urls:

> \product\123
>
> \product\product-name-123
>
> \product\another-product-123
>
> \product\john-doe-123

and you would still get the product with id `123`, though the urls are different.

5. Next step is to let the controller know that it has to use a special filer

   ```
   [SlugToId]
   public ActionResult Index(int id)
   {
   }
   ```